Growing food by firelight
The question of what the citizens of fantasy underground kingdoms eat is usually handwaved to: "they trade for their food", or "they eat mushrooms".  I would like my undergrounders to grow reasonably conventional carbohydrate and vegetable crops using something akin to vertical farming/hydroponics, but lit by candlelight/lamplight carefully redirected with mirrors and lenses.
How much fuel (coal, wood or lamp oil) would you need to burn to produce enough light to grow enough food to feed a family? Fantasy setting, so light from open flames only, no arclight or electricity. Obviously I'm expecting this to be wildly impractical, but it would be nice for it to merely feel disbelievable rather than jarringly preposterous.

That is not one question.

There are some crops, for example Canabis sativa, which are commonly grown under artificial lighting in some countries. You may want to check what is the required level of illumination...

@AlexP Grow lights range from about 4200 to over 100,000 lumens per m^2 depending on what you are growing and what stage of growth your plant is in.  That said, any plant grown for food tends to be in the upper range of this spectrum, at least during the phase of growth that it is actively producing its fruit/bulb/etc.  So, even if marijuana can be grown at lower intensities, that does not make it comparable to growing edible foods.

Instead of light produced by fire, have outside lenses and mirrors that direct sunlight through windows. That light can be directed down by more mirrors. There is a bit of loss with each mirror but with enough outside light, there might be a way to grow stuff.

We have hosted a lot of questions about food for underground societies. Also, you are allowed to ask one and only one question per post. VTC:Needs More Focus.

@JBH yes, there have been many questions about feeding underground societies, but as far as I can tell, this is the first one to propose raising plants with firelight.   As for the 1 question thing: I'm on the fence about if this actually needs a VTC.  While it is worded as 2 seperate "questions", the second one is clearly just a qualifier for a best possible answer since it is is really just asking respondents to clarify their outcomes by citing specific crops.

If they can grow enough wood to grow by firelight, they can just grow crops were they cut down the wood.

It's at least as credible as eating mushrooms.

I removed the "what crops" question, which as Nosajimiki says was definitely incidental.

@DavidR: You’d need a capture area which is pretty much the same size as your field.

Voting to Reopen since the primary concern about this being two questions has already been fixed, and the issue of it being a duplicate was never valid since no other questions are specifically about using fire light.

Indeed, I was just thinking about coming back and accepting your answer ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Probable frame challenge. On RL Earth, photosynthesis is adapted to sunlight, not firelight. Energy-management-wise, it's nonsense to stimulate the synthesis of carbohydrates and lipids by burning vegetable fuel, which is essentially these same carbohydrates and fat.

(Well, that's basically what the accepted answer says). The only realistic way to grow crops underground is by bringing real sunlight down there: think mirrors, optical fibers, catadioptric ceilings and such, not firelight.

The question is about fuel requirements.  But oxygen requirements to burn that much fuel underground would be at least as daunting as collecting the required amount of fuel in the first place.

This is "Jarringly Preposterous"
The sun is a lot brighter than candles or campfires.  The average candle produces about 12.6 lumens.  Sunlight averages about 127,000 lumens per square meter meaning you'd need about 10,000 candles per square meter of farmland to replace sunlight, and the average farm can grow about 0.5-3kg per food per square meter. A 12 hour candle weighs 43 grams and your average vegetable plant takes 40-90 days to mature.  That means you'd have to burn 5.7 to 77.4 tons of candles to grow 1 kg of food. Sufficeless to say, this is WAY less economically viable than simply trading for or stealing food from the surface races.  Since your average family of 5 consumes 1200-1700kg of food per year, that means that you'll need about 7000-132000 tons of candles.  I've tried doing calculations with wood, natural gas, limelights, and coal, and these are even less heat-to-light efficient than candles.  If you don't mind adding some mid-1800s tech to your setting, gas mantles are about 15-30 times as efficient as candles... but they also release radioactive gases and should never be used in a closed space.
As for "what crop works best", tubers like potatoes tend to yield the highest food output per sunlight, but that does not mean you can actually get away with just eating potatoes all day, every day.  People need (and more importantly, demand) more than one kind of food to live off of. So, while 7000 tons of candles might get you the light you need for an all potato diet, to get a rich diet in grains, fruits, vegetables, dairy, and meat, you will have to invest in much closer to the higher end of this range.
Furthermore, apart from being too expensive, fires are simply WAY too hot.  Your average candle puts out about 5 watts of heat per lumen of light, but the sun puts out about 200 lumens per watt of heat, meaning sunlight is about 1000 times cooler for its brightness than your average fire. So, lighting enough candles (or making any sort of fires) close enough to plants to grow them would also burn them.
Either your fire or your crops need to be magic
That said, this is fantasy; so, there may be a couple of options available to you. Any problem that can not be solved by science can be solved by magic; so, here are a few alternative ideas that might get the job done.

Sun Stones: Glowing magic stones are a common trope in any fantasy setting; so, why not use these to your advantage.  Your people have used magical stones to trap the light of the sun so that like the sun, they glow with an intense light without putting out an intense heat.
Faerie Fire:  Faerie fire is another common fantasy trope.  Faerie fires are magically summoned fires that are often described as dim, cool, and pleasant.  However, faeries are also knowns as creatures of nature known to help plants grown and to usher in the seasons.  Perhaps you do not need your light to be intense if the light you do have carries the quintessential essence of life and fertility.
Pyrosynthetic plants: Perhaps your underground people grow plants that thrive directly in the fires.  Instead of needing to turn light into energy, they can do it directly with the energy output of a fire.  Plants only use a tiny fraction of the energy from the sun converting about 3-5 watts per square meter into energy; so, if you make up a plant that can turn fire directly into energy, then the energy of a single 12-hour candle could sustain a square meter of plants for up to month.  So, imagine you have some kind of seeds.  Your underground people could light a coal fire and cover it with these seeds that will then absorb the energy of the fire and grow into large fruits that will contain all of the energy the plant will ever need.  You eat the fruits you need to live off and plant the rest which will themselves grow into leafless flowers that produce more seeds in total darkness using nothing but stored energy having a life cycle similar to Mayflies.

Final Consideration
Even with a vastly improved or magical solution, heat in an underground world is very hard to dissipate.  Even small fires will over time trap more and more heat in the walls turning your underground city into a giant oven.  So, you will likely need an underground place with running water to take away the extra heat... not to mention a flowing source of water would be good for drinking, irrigation, and waste disposal.

Are you sure that lumens (of visible light) are the right attribute, as opposed to raw calorimetry? Plants do a lot of their photosynthesis in the IR. Plants are also notorious for dying for no reason if they don't get things exactly their way, but as long as we're assuming that they don't...

@gs Photosynthesis primarily occurs within the visible light spectrum (particularly red and blue light).  It is way less efficient at absorbing IR, Green, or UV light; so, lumens is a much better measure than raw calorimetry https://boulderlamp.com/light-spectrum-and-photosynthesis/. While most of the sun's heat comes in the form of IR light, this energy is mostly wasted by plants.

So the sun is more efficient in terms of light vs. heat because the sun is so much hotter that a larger proportion of its photons are high-energy. (close enough to 50% to use that number for these kinds of discussions.)  So, if instead of candles you used an efficient burner and a mantle you could get your light to heat ratio to be much more favorable. You'd still have to burn way too much though, unless there's a truly massive gas deposit or something. Might be easier if the plants do some kind of chemosynthesis instead of photosynthesis.

Its fundamentally impossible to provide more energy via firelight than is required to produce the fuel for the fire. To simplify: a piece of common rush that produces one hour of rush-light takes about 3 months of sunlight to grow in the first place. Same with wood, tar, pine resin, bamboo, beeswax (in a round-about way) etc etc.
So, it is never going to make more sense to burn plants to shine light at crops, than to just eat the original plants.
The only solution is to somehow get the fuel "for free" (fossil fuel that already has the solar energy trapped in it) from coal, crude oil, natural gas etc.
Then again, if you have coal or oil, why not TRADE it for food? It would be significantly more efficient.
The closest thing to a solution is to find a way to farm crops next to some safely accessed lava flow, where the light, heat, and volcanic nutritients are not only free, but cannot be sold.
This however would require you to rethink what you mean by "crops". Think less "wheat and potatoes" and more "fireproof extremophile lichen".

I was thinking bananas

Lava light redirected by mirrors? Would that be able to grow potatoes?

Lava light comes with a lot of heat. You don't want to be near lava underground (when no cooling means are available)

why not turn the oil into food directly ?

@DaniëlvandenBerg. Nah, the useful light from lava is far weaker than the sheer heat it gives off (or to be more precise, most of the radiation lava radiates is not useful for photosynthesis, but thermal radiation). You are more likely to melt the mirror than help the potato grow. If you find a magma flow shiny enough to provide light for photosynthesis, both you and the potato would be baked thoroughly just by being near it.

@Pica. Turning fossil fuel into food is technically possible, but would require such a high level of technological (or magical?) sophistication that the setting changes completely

You haven't actually answered whether it would be possible to use fossil fuels to grow crops, just thrown back a hypothetical "why wouldn't you trade?" - to which there are plenty of possible answers, which this isn't the right place to discuss.

Well, fossil fuels are basically the same as firelight same as sunlight. Its all sunlight in the end, stored in various forms.

@GoingDurden well, you could grow bacterial mats of Paraperlucidibaca, Cycloclasticus, and Zhongshania. If you cook them, you should be at least left with some sort of protein. And if you cook things long enough, lots of biological poisons break down.

@IMSoP, Fossil fuels could be burned for light, to shine at the crops (though I think only methane/natural gas would be sensible to use that way, other fossil fuels produce to much smoke and damp). Rock oil can also be turned into fertilizer if they are sophisticated enough. The problem with all those solutions is that the types of plants that can grow in a cave by firelight tend to be nyctophile lampenflora, which is not particularly nutritious.

@Pica, yeah sure, if OP moved away from standard "crops" and towards bacterial mats, lichen, lampenflora, algae etc, this becomes manageable. Standard crops like potatoes or wheat are no-go, but there is plenty of nyctophile plants, bacteria and fungi that can be grown instead.

As an alternative, underground kingdom residents could grow potatoes at the surface and harvest them from below (but this does not answer the question).

"It is never going to make more sense to burn plants to shine light at crops, than to just eat the original plant" - it is if you can't eat the original plant. This is like saying that people should just eat grass, instead of feeding it to cows and eating their meat. You would of course need a plant that has abundant access to sunshine, but harvesting trees outside the caves to burn inside could work.

Nope. Not even close. Light is not a problem; heat and ventilation is. It is difficult to dissipate heat underground: the surrounding rock absorbs it and then radiates it back, effectively turning the caverns into an oven. And while in theory ventilation can be provided by running a chimney up to the surface, you would not want to be underground if that chimney is ever blocked, which would be a very obvious thing for any besieging army to try to do.

Light is most definitely a problem. Yes, crops can be grown using artificial lighting, but you need really strong illumination, thousands of times more than what a candle can provide. (And candles are really really expensive. If you have the money for a thousand candles just go buy the food from the market and still have money for hundreds of candles.)

@AlexP, thank you. No, light is not a problem. If you need the light of a few thousand candles, this is easily solved by lighting a few thousand candles, or some other cheaper fuel which produces the same amount of light... at which point you will have enough light but will promptly bake and/or suffocate.

Even with a vent, the walls of the caverns will still take on the heat and not be able to dissipate it.  Breathing you can solve with a vent, but not the part where you cook yourself in the process.

If you have a vent, it can let in light too.

@RichardKirk, thank you. Yes, and consider that to provide adequate light, you would need a vent the size of the field, and wider still at the top so as not to cast too much of a shadow on it. You tell me where the vent ends and a trench begins.

All that being said, there ARE plants that can grow with extremely low levels of artificial light, the so called lampenflora. Technically, you can grow whole fields of plants with minimum light from candles and mirrored shafts, with no of the issues you wrote about. the problem is, no known species of lampenflora is nutritious enough to be a staple crop, so either OP would have to invent a new plant species for their story, or the crops would be grown just for the vitamins not calories, which would be provided by something else.

@GoingDurden, thank you. There's that, and the OP asked if it's possible to grow "enough food to feed a family" with firelight; so vitamins alone won't do.

Growing mushrooms might fit the bill after all
As the other answers have pointed out, the light of a fire will not do much to let photosynthesizing plants grow. So if you want your underground farms, mushrooms might be the thing to grow after all.
Granted, that's not exactly "reasonably conventional carbohydrate and vegetable crops" - but mushrooms are tasty, and don't need light. What they DO need is biomatter to consume - mushrooms are closer to animals than plants in how they get their energy (they're a third kingdom, actually. Quite fascinating).
So instead of importing thousands of tons of wood, oil or wax for burning - just import wood, straw, sawdust, whatever, and let the shrooms grow on that. It will (if you, the author, make it so) be much cheaper than importing actual food, you can place the farms vertical or however you want as long as every shroom gets biomatter to grow on and some water, and you can still have candles or torches if your people need them to see the mushrooms. Or to keep away subterranean pests.
To be clear, you're not handwaving it with "they eat mushrooms". You have a proper supply chain of food for the shrooms, farmers, and so on there.

Wouldn't you know it: it is difficult.
Not necessarily impossible though. Probably.
Preposterous? Certainly! At least financially speaking.
TLDR: Produce city-gas and use that in gas lamps. Optimize by using incandescent gas mantles. About 500-2000kg bituminous coal/person/day.
NOTE: Trading will allways be cheaper. Probably even in war. Those are highly valuable fossil resources you'll be "wasting".
While I tried my best to keep my calculations sound, I may well be off by a fair bit.
PRELUDE: Let's collect some basics first:
1. Basic ways of lighting.
You explicitly excluded electrical light, and you mentioned open flames.
If you're talking purely camp fire, that'll be a hard no. To much heat and too little light in photosynteticly active spectrum.
But if you are smart about you fire, and use mirrors etc. there might be a chance. Barely.
That said, what about other light sources?
Lava streams, skylights, bioluminescence, radioluminescence, (cough, cough, "handwavy magic rocks") ...
All valid sources of light.
2. Ways of food production.
You asked for photosyntesis for food production. (At least you asked for "by firelight").
Obviously it is going to be easier, if this method of food production is not your main source of food, but supplemental.
You could produce normal crops or grow seaweeds and algae, which might be more effective.
Other than photosyntesis, there are radiosyntetic fungi and many chemosyntetic organisms.
Maybe you can grow some nutritious sludge directly from some coal residues. Probably not too tasty but it may be your
secure food supply, in case of war or famine. Heating up your brown coal, bituminous coal or pitch may help you fungi/sludge
digesting it. Or your crafty mountain dwellers may be able to destill some substances from it, that can be used in food.
Coal may be syntesized to fertilizers or even directly to edible substances like sugars starches or proteins. (Probably not in your setting though)
And obviously you'll supplement with whatever fungi and critters you may grow or herd within the mountain.
Science basics of photosyntesis:
Efficiency and frequencies
Photosyntesis of Glucose requires at least 8-10 photones per molecule of CO2 used.
The photosynteticly active radiation (PAR) ranges mostly between 400 and 700 nm, peaking in efficiency at 610-630 nm (red-orange).
The Gibbs free energy for converting one mole of CO2 to glucose is 114kcal. 8 mole of photons at 600 nm contain 381kcal.
This would put the theoretical limit of efficiency for photosyntesis of glucose to 30%.
(Actually photosyntesis can use light up to 720 nm as long as there is some light at under 680 nm as well...)
(The energy of a mole of photons is E=h*c/lambda)
For sunlight and common plants the efficiency drops.

Sunlight has only 45% in the PAR (30% => 11%)
Reflection, suboptimal lighting, respiration, unused rest energy in green-blue photones (11% => 3-6%)
Crop-plants "waste" energy on inedible parts (=>1-2%)

Of 100% Sunlight hitting the leaf:
100%    sunlight → non-bioavailable photons waste is 47%, leaving
53%     (in the 400–700 nm range) → 30% of photons are lost due to incomplete absorption, leaving
37%     (absorbed photon energy) → 24% is lost due to wavelength-mismatch degradation to 700 nm energy, leaving
28.2%   (sunlight energy collected by chlorophyll) → 68% is lost in conversion of ATP and NADPH to d-glucose, leaving
9%      (collected as sugar) → 35–40% of sugar is recycled/consumed by the leaf in dark and photo-respiration, leaving
5.4%    net leaf efficiency.
What can we optimize?

The type of plant:
Algae are better than crops.
C4 plants like Maize/Corn and sugar cane have a higher efficiency than C3 plants like wheat (4.3% vs. 3.5% peak).
Lighting conditions:
Longer "Days". With algae even continuous lighting.
Frequency-matching (We'll get to that)
Temperature & pest controll:
There's less heat, less heat fluctuation and less/no common pests.
CO2 levels:
More CO2 makes plants grow faster (up to certain limits)

If we can manage to match the photons better, we may increase the Efficiency in the first few steps.
Say we can produce mostly matched photons, some 85% in the PAR of which we manage to absorb 80% and since they're mostly
closer to 700 nm we only lose 10% to wavelength degredation. That would move our total step-3 efficiency from 28.2 to 53.6%.
That would almost double our efficiency.
ways of lighting
Obviously your mountain dwellers won't have LED growth lights. So, how do we light it?
Skylights:
Sunlight is too intense anyway. We might stretch it to light about 3 times the normal area. Maybe even five times.
Still, while we could use mirrors an long straight shafts, thats hardly "underground".
Luminiscence:
Some things glow if hit by radiation (often called phosphors).
Some may glow softly, but for a long time after being hit by light (phosphorescence)
Some may glow if close to radioactive sources (radioluminiscence)
Some things glow if rubbed or deformed (tribo or piezo-luminiscence)
Some chemicals may emmit light (chemoluminiscence)
=> the effect is usually fairly small. You might grow some algae, but even then, the output is probably not worth the hassle.
Even with radioluminescence, the radiation will probably kill off your algae before you get any noticeable growth.
Magic or bioluminescence:
Magic probably requires some source of energy. The mage will need more calories than are produced.
Maybe they can syphon energy from the fire or from magma / lava / mana lines. But thats fairly handwavy.
Same for bioluminescence. Better to eat what-ever-glows directly or feed it to something that can.
Lava streams:
Produces a lot of heat and fairly little light in PAR. What-ever it's free, isn't it? And not something you can trade.
Use a metal mirror to reflect its light through a piece of glass. This should strip the infra-red out.
Keep your glass water-cooled so you can focus more light through the glass disc without melting it.
MAIN PART
** Lighting using Fire **
Ah, now we're baking. You mentioned it already, and we may have some changes to help out.
Fire emmits light, but as with lava, your campfire produces fairly little PAR per heat (2-4%).
If we raise the temperature we get more light. At 3000K we get about 8%. That's about as hot as a halogen light bulb
at their filament. At 5600K we reach sunlight. Your campfire won't be as hot. But ...
Your mountain dwellers may produce town gas (city gas, synt gas, coke gas, water gas, all more or less the same stuff).
Town gas is a mixture of coal gas and water gas, which are usually produced in the same process anyway.
Coal gas is produced by heating coal or coke without air, until the remaining tar turns to volatile hydrocarbons.
By blowing steam through the glowing coal, the carbon reacts with the steam producing a mixture of mostly CO (50%),
H2 (30%), CO2 (15%) and CH4 (5%) (ratios max vary; adding more steam produces more H2 and CO2).
Town gas burns hot, blue-ish red-ish and fairly faint since it produces no sut that would glow.
Burn it with oxygen and point it to a piece of quick lime and it will glow brightly. You just re-invented the limelight of Mr. Drummond.
But we can do better: If you put somethin very thin into the flame you dont need to build high-pressure burners.
Sprinkle quick lime dust or magnesia dust through the flame and you got some light. Sprinkling again and again is tedious.
Ah, but we can do better: How about incandescent gas mantles? Make a stocking from easy-to-burn fibre like linen, or
if available use cotton. Soak it in a solution of some metal salts you want to use or dust it in ground down magnesia.
The flame will burn off the fibres, leaving behind a very thin and fragile shell of metal salts that will glow in the flame.
But we can do even better: Not ony does the metal salt glow from the heat, but it will also glow in the emmision spectra
of its ions. This is more efficient than blackbody radiation and to our advantage. While modern gas mantles use Cerium
oxides and thorium oxides or yttrium oxides we don't need something quite as fancy.
If you ever did flame tests in school chemistry, you'll know that Lithium salts turn a flame red. From old street lights
you know the yellow of Sodium. Well, quick lime is Calcium oxide, which glows yellow and orange. To be more precise:
Lithium at 671 nm, Sodium at 589 nm and Calcium at 622 and 553 nm, all three are in the PAR and close to the most
efficient wavelengths as well. Sodium is found in salt and Calcium is found in lime / quick lime.
By adding these salts to our gas mantles we can get rather efficient growth lights.
How efficient? About 5lm/W or half as efficient as a light-bulb. Keeping in mind that fossile power plants themself
are ownly 50-60% efficient, we're closer to nearly lightbulb efficiency. And it is in good wavelength for growing.
With the "salted water gas lights" and feeding the plant rests to the pigs or gassifying them you can assume we get the
whole 2% (maybe even slightly more) light-to-plant-matter efficiency. With the lights own efficiency and the efficiency
of town gas production we get 3-4%. This combines to 6-8 of 10 000. So you need 10 000 / 6 = 1666 times as much energy
in coal, than you get in food. per day you need ca 3000 kcal so the coal must provide 5 000 000 kcal per day.
Bituminous coal has about 7000 kcal/kg so that's roughly 700kg. Even recycling half the energy for process heat,
thats still 350kg per person per day. Even if we're optimistic assuming the efficiency gains from growth light and we are really good at producing water gas, your sugar-cane and corn eating dwarves wont go under 250kg per day. If they eat algae maybe that will reduce to 150-ish kg put that's the absolute hard limit. It is far more likely that you need something like 4 tonnes of coal per day.
And you still have the problem of removing your waste heat ... and of ventilation.

This is an absolutely fantastic answer. Well done

You're Not Thinking Big Enough
Skip the fire, live off of coal
There are bacteria which eat hydrocarbons.  You could have an entire ecosystem based on some reasonably plentiful (though not totally unlimited) resource underground.  Mushrooms feed on bacteria which feed on minerals (including coal or oil), and you skip needing fire to make light to grow surface plants.
As an added bonus, the progression of these life-processes along coal or other mineral veins might soften up the rock and make tunnel excavation easier.  And you could handwave that a byproduct is free oxygen, so that's why you don't need (as much) ventilation from the surface.  At the same time, exhausted tunnels would gradually become difficult to live in as the coal ran out and the processes wound down - meaning there would be constant, gradual resettlement, and endless, ancient, barely inhabitable tunnels left abandoned.  (This sounds pretty cool.)
The lifecycles underground might include phosphorescence, and the ancient settlers who moved down from the surface into this foreign ecosystem (long back in the lost mists of history) originally discovered caverns full of dimly glowing life, inexplicable but persistent, among which they first settled.

Efficiency is the problem.
Unlike a campfire, gaslight would probably be bright and white enough for some plants and you can make it from wood or coal fairly easily.
Plants only store ~2% of the incoming light energy (at least for sunlight spectrum) as carbohydrates.
I can’t find any numbers on the efficiency of gaslight, but let’s just assume it’s also 2% efficient (just a guess, incandescent lights are in that ballpark).
You’d need 2500 times more fuel than the crops you produce.
So you’d have to burn 2500J worth of gas to produce a single Joule of food energy.
Put in other words: A whole kg of propane gas (50MJ) would only give you 20kJ of food. That’s 4.8kcal, or a bit more than a gram of sugar. You’d need more than 400kg of gas for every adult, every day. As a sidenote, coal has about half the energy density of propane gas.
All the lost energy is heat. So you’d need a ton of ventilation and cooling.

Edit: When you think about it, it’s actually not that bad. Heating a single family home with oil or gas burns between 2000kg to 3000kg for a whole winter. That’s also around 50kg on the worst days. So your underground farm is only 8 times worse than a German single family home in the worst of winter.

Unrefined natural gases are mostly Methane and Propane and have very non-luminous flames; so, they will not produce significant amounts of useful light.  Butane is probably the most luminous of natural gases, but only makes up a tiny fraction of natural gases and has to be separated from other gases using high-tech methods. Burning a mixed natural gas will only output about 0.01-0.05% of its energy in the visible light spectrum  vs sunlight which is 42% visible light; so, your calculations will be off by several orders of magnitude because photosynthesis happens in the visible light spectrum.

@Nosajimiki: What if you don’t use the flame directly? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_mantle or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limelight

Gas mantles get a much better conversion (about 30%), but they use Yttrium and Lanthanum which no one learned to refine until the 1800s; so, they are beyond the tech level of a typical fantasy race.  They also release radium when heated; so, if used at a large scale in an underground environment, the radioactive/toxic fumes would render your cavern uninhabitable pretty quickly.

Limelights are more efficient than burning straight gas, but they are still less than 1% efficient.

Limelights require a jet of compressed air and a high ignition temperature (often supplied by a gas preburner stage) to get the calcium oxide to burn rather than a flammable gas.

Assuming very good ventilation and high standards of flame keeping, to ensure you are burning all of the gas and not having leaks; Acetylene is you friend. It can be made using water, limestone/shell/bone, and some wood, or coke, as a carbon feed stock. The flame it produces is an intense white light source that peaks slightly more blue that natural sunlight. You'd need a lot of gas but you can line your furnaces with lime to make the calcium carbonate as a byproduct of other heat dependent production then you just add water, and for that you can use waste water. Acetylene is not just flammable but explosive at minute levels if it leaks into the general air of the grow space so you cannot let that happen but it gets around issues of fire light wavelength and the caloric concerns around burning material producing less energy than it's inputs by using wastes and existing processes.

I had been thinking of adding carbide/acetylen lights to my answer but carbide is usually produced with electric arc furnaces at 2200-2300 C and electricity was excluded in the question. Even coal fires in forges tend not to go above 1600 C, but I'm tickled by the idea of using town gas to produce Acetylene ... Or use hydrogen produced by blowing steam through glowing iron pipes? That'll be hot enough.
The efficiency will be lower, but carbide/acetylene is always nice to have. And it might be easier on the lamp side of things.
So many nice options when using gasses. I'd love to trade ideas

@Teck-freak Calcium Carbide was originally produced as a byproduct of using blast furnaces that were lined with lime, the yield wasn't particularly high but you didn't want it to be because it represented degradation of the furnace lining, The temperatures were, relatively, low but the excessively high carbon supply meant the reaction took place slowly but steadily anyway.

True. I didn't mean to imply it isn't possible without arc furnaces, but merely that it is harder, low-yield and less efficient. That was the reason why I was thinking about how to actively produce Calcium Carbide by gas burners....
"byproduct of using blast furnaces" ... I thought so, but I couldn't find a source explicitly stating it, on the fly. And if the mountain dwellers large-scale refine their iron ore anyway, using such a byproduct would make sense.

Lava separated by natural glass and a river for cooling
This is stretching the limits of what could "naturally" occur, but here goes.
As some have suggested -- lava does produce light. A typical temperature is something like ~1300K, comparable to that of the center of a candle, well below the ~5800K blackbody temperature of the sun. A very large lava river could produce enough light for a farm, but would pretty much always lead to far too much heat. (Perhaps the plants could adapt to the heat, but the human farmers would need to as well.) So that leaves the question of how to separate the lava by a great distance, insulating away the heat, while preserving the light.
Glass does form naturally. It is usually not particularly clear, but it can be. So, scenario: a large, thick layer of high-clarity glass above underground lava river. Infrared will be absorbed by the glass in the first few centimeters/meters, protecting from radiative heat transfer, but allowing visible light mostly through. In a very large cavern, this could keep the whole area illuminated pretty well 24/7, definitely enough to grow small crops by.
Heat will of course slowly transfer through the glass just by conduction and would warm up the area. But, we're assuming anyway that there must be plenty of water for irrigation, it seems fine to assume that there's a river that can carry excess heat away. Streams are fast and water has a high heat capacity. If this is running over the glass (also permitting light through!), it could maintain reasonable temperatures while letting most light through.
It would also be an absolutely stunning display visually: a clear floor with a river flowing over it, peering through meters of clear glass to magma below, the red glow refracting onto the ceiling of the cave as the water tumbles over it.

Naturally occuring LED organisms, converting electeic potentisl via roots into light could work. at least when it comes to the sunlight rocket equation of food. How to pieces of rock would naturally become a battery isolated from one another only by meters? no idea .

https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/bkkj22/vegetation_around_a_lightbulb_in_a_cave/
